# Simulation of Poisson data with a endogenous regressor

Tags: r, regression, poisson-distribution, simulation, endogeneity

My simulation setup goes like this:

I draw my dependend variable as $Y\sim \text{Poi}\left(\lambda\right)$

where $\lambda = \exp\left(\beta_0 + \beta_1x_1 + \beta_2z + u\right)$

and $z = \gamma_0 + \gamma_1x_1 + v$

$u\sim N(0,1)$, $v\sim N(0,1)$

The endogenous regressor $z$ within the $\lambda$-equation is now being created by letting $\text{Cov}(u,v)=p$ using a Cholesky-Decomposition approach.

The issue I'm currently facing seems to be silly but even if I set $p=0$ I'll get a biased estimate of $\beta_0$. This seems strange as $v,u$ are chosen such that they are zero on average.

Why is there a bias within $\widehat{\beta}_0$?

Comment: When you analyze your simulated data, you are leaving $u$ out of the regression model, yes? Just want to make sure I understand what you're doing.

Comment: Yes thats true. I think my silly mistake was that when I'll estimate the $\lambda$ equation with $z$ as defined above I'll get $\widehat{\beta}$ as an estimate for $\beta_0+\gamma_0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think one issue that is occurring is that with a GLM, if you have random effects (such as $u$) that average out to 0, this does *not* mean that their effect on the average comes out to be zero. This is due to Jensen's inequality.

To illustrate this very simply: consider $x_1 = -1, x_2 = 1$. Clearly, $\bar x = 0$. But $\bar{(e^{x})} \approx 1.5 ≠ 1.0 = e^{\bar x}$.

This is a very common mistake that is made in interpreting fixed effects in a generalized mixed effects model. In the case of an identity link, the fixed effect can be interpreted as the population average. This is *not* the case for other link functions.

In terms of accounting for the random effect $u$, this actually can be done with generalized mixed effects models. Consider the following fits in R:

```
library(lme4)
u <- rnorm(500)
#Random Effects
y <- rpois(500, lambda = exp(u + 1))
#Observed outcomes. Note that intercept = 1
id <- 1:500
#Only one observation per subject!
fit_glm <- glm(y ~ 1, family = poisson)
#Fitting a standard glm without accounting for random effect
fit_glmm <- glmer(y ~ (1|id), family = poisson)
#Fitting accounting for random effect
summary(fit_glm)
#Note that we clearly are not capturing true intercept (1).
#Again, due to Jensen's inequality
summary(fit_glmm)
#Now that we have accounted for these random effects, it seems that we have 
#an unbiased estimator for the intercept!
```

Comment: To follow up on that: do you know any reference or means to create a arrival process where one co-variable itself is endogenous and depends upon the arrival rate itself? For instance in demand situations if a high arrival rate is observed (multiple purchases of a product) the firm will increase their price (which will then be endogenous as depending upon demand).

Comment: Sorry to disappoint, but not my field, so I can't claim expertise. I can see why you were getting biases in $\hat{\beta_o}$, but I could only make up ways I would handle this rather than point you to established literature that I am familiar with.

Comment: As what I've described above is a rather simplified version of what I'm actually trying to do it would help greatly if you could give my some hints?

Comment: In terms of dealing with the random effect (which is a part but perhaps not all of your problem), I've added an example of using glmm's to address this.

Comment: I've not thought about dealing with this problem with explicitly using a random effects model. Thank you for the insight.

Comment: For the recorded, not the most generalizable solution: for example, would clearly fail if we were to use a Gaussian mixed effects model with only one observation per subject, as the estimated residual error would be 0.

Comment: That is true. Besides that I'm not quite sure whether it is possible to induce endogeneity this way as the random effect $u$ now explicitly models the dependence between $z$ and the "error term". Nevertheless there could be a way of exploiting the mixed effects framework to achieve what I'm trying to do.