# Residuals with glm / glmer don't have null mean

Tags: residuals, logit, glmm, lme4-nlme

I am trying to fit accuracy data (taking values 0 or 1) using glmer and I am puzzled to observe that the residuals of the model don't have a null mean. Wasn't this the whole point of the optimization..? 
Does it mean that the model fails to converge although there was no warning message? 
I observe the same behavior with simple glm models.
My data has very high mean accuracy (.88), could it be part of the problem?

An example model:

```
final<- glmer(acc ~ group*I(soa/10) + group*I(scale(soa*soa)) + 
            (1 |suj),  family=binomial(link="probit") ,data.f, glmerControl(optimizer="bobyqa", optCtrl = list(maxfun = 150000)))
```

and here the binned plot for fitted vs residuals

```
binnedplot(predict(final), resid(final), cex.pts=1, col.int="black")
```

[image]

Thank you very much for your answers.

(A reproducible example can be found [here](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B0gyPoMB36PFMzMwNFFRWEI2a1U&usp=sharing))

Comment: this is probably a Jensen's inequality issue https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen's_inequality ... can we have a (simple) reproducible example please?

Comment: e.g. http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/162676/simulation-of-poisson-data-with-a-endogenous-regressor/162694#162694

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer Dr Bolker.

I'm afraid there is a need for a certain number of data points to observe this strange pattern so I put a dataframe and a minimal script on this drive:

https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B0gyPoMB36PFMzMwNFFRWEI2a1U&usp=sharing

Comment: Do you know if that completely invalidates my model or if I am authorized to draw some conclusions e.g. on the effect of the predictor SOA (considering that the residuals all seem equally biased when plotted against SOA)?