# Is there a limit proportion of 0 and 1 to fit binary data using glm (link "logit")

Tags: generalized-linear-model, binary-data, logit, glmm

In relation with my other question [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/215280/residuals-with-glm-glmer-dont-have-null-mean) where I observe a strange behavior of the residuals after fitting binary data using glm/glmer, I now wonder:

Are there boundaries on the proportion of 0 (or 1) necessary in order to be able to regress binary data? If there are too many 1 compared to the 0 or conversely, does it prevent attempts of modeling?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no hard limits aside from the fact that your data can't be 100% one class. It is true, however, that the less balanced your classes are, the harder it is to learn to distinguish them.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Would you happen to know what could cause the residuals to be biased and not have a null mean ?